# Taylor expansion development related to Bernouli numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

So I have the function $  g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_k}{k!}x^k $ where $B_k$ is the $k$'th Bernouli number.

I want to show that $g(x)(e^{x} - 1) = x$

I tried showing this by developing the taylor expansion for $e^x$ and by taking the first term from it and by performing index manipulation.

I got that the taylor expansion for $e^x$ after substructing $1$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$

However, I wasnt able to show the equation above.

Comment: What is your definition of the $B_k$? To me, this equation is the definition (as the coefficients in the exponential series expansion of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$)

Comment: @CalvinKhor $B_k = -\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k+1}{j}\cdot B_j$